# Error: "Builder failed to create phone auth options" in Unity C#

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a mobile application using Unity and C#, and I'm implementing phone authentication using Firebase. However, when I try to create phone authentication using the Firebase Authentication SDK, I encounter an error message stating "Builder failed to create phone auth options." Here is the snap shot:
[When I press the send OTP button it triggers the verifyphonenumber method and that method triggers the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzmBj.jpg)
Here is the code:

```
private void VerifyPhoneNumber()
    {
        phoneAuthProvider = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(firebaseAuth);

        phoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber(countryCode + phoneNumber, null,
          verificationCompleted: (credential) =>
          {
              Debug.Log("Verification complete: " + credential);
              // Auto-sms-retrieval or instant validation has succeeded (Android only).
              // There is no need to input the verification code.
              // `credential` can be used instead of calling GetCredential().
          },
          verificationFailed: (error) =>
          {
              Debug.Log("The verification code was not sent: " + error);
              // The verification code was not sent.
              // `error` contains a human readable explanation of the problem.
          },
          codeSent: (id, token) =>
          {
              verificationId = id;
              verificationMessagePanel.SetActive(true);
              phoneNumberVerificationPanel.SetActive(false);
              Debug.Log("Verification code was successfully sent via SMS: " + id);
              // Verification code was successfully sent via SMS.
              // `id` contains the verification id that will need to passed in with
              // the code from the user when calling GetCredential().
              // `token` can be used if the user requests the code be sent again, to
              // tie the two requests together.
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut: (id) =>
          {
              Debug.Log("`id` contains the verification id of the request that timed out: " + id);
              // Called when the auto-sms-retrieval has timed out, based on the given
              // timeout parameter.
              // `id` contains the verification id of the request that timed out.
          });
    }
```

I have verified that I have the latest version of the Firebase SDK (11.0.0) and that all the necessary dependencies are installed.

I tried using the PhoneAuthOptions.Builder method but it does not exist