# Unity on Android Firebase phone auth error: VerifyPhoneNumber: builder faild to create PhoneAuhtOptions

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to implement Unity Firebase phone authentication on Android using the following code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase.Auth;

public class AuthClient : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var text = FindObjectOfType<Text>();

        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                Firebase.FirebaseApp app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
                PhoneAuthProvider provider = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance);

                try
                {
                    var provOption = new PhoneAuthOptions
                    {
                        PhoneNumber = [Phone number example],
                        TimeoutInMilliseconds = 100 * 1000,
                        ForceResendingToken = null,
                    };

                    provider.VerifyPhoneNumber
                    (
                        provOption,
                        verificationCompleted: (credential) =>
                        {
                            // Some codes
                        },
                        verificationFailed: (error) =>
                        {
                            // Some codes
                        },
                        codeSent: (id, token) =>
                        {
                            // Some Codes
                        },
                        codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut: (id) =>
                        {
                            // Some codes
                        }
                    );
                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                    text.text = e.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("An error occurred while checking dependencies. ");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, the following error is being thrown:

```
VerifyPhoneNumber: builder faild to create PhoneAuhtOptions
```

(Yeah, "faild" is exactly part of the printed message.)

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?

PS. I found a similar issue here, but there is no solution available: [Error: "Builder failed to create phone auth options" in Unity C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76245688/error-builder-failed-to-create-phone-auth-options-in-unity-c-sharp)

Comment: Thats not how to spell phoneauthoptions either. What drunk person commited that error

Answer (score 0):

Was facing same issue but was able to fix with some changes. Here is the code hope it will help some one.

```
 public class FirebasePhoneAuth : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_InputField phoneNumber;
    [SerializeField] private TMP_InputField userVerificationCode;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private PhoneAuthProvider provider;

    private ForceResendingToken verificationToken;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        provider = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(firebaseAuth);
    }

    public void VerifyPhoneNumber()
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
           
                try
                {
                    var provOption = new PhoneAuthOptions
                    {
                        PhoneNumber = "+91" + long.Parse(phoneNumber.text),
                        TimeoutInMilliseconds = 100 * 1000,
                        ForceResendingToken = null,
                    };
                    provider.VerifyPhoneNumber
                    (
                        provOption,
                        verificationCompleted: (credential) =>
                        {
                            Debug.Log($"Verification complete : {credential}");
                        },
                        verificationFailed: (error) =>
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Verification failed :" + error);

                        },
                        codeSent: (id, token) =>
                        {
                            PlayerPrefs.SetString("verificationId", id);
                            verificationToken = token;
                            Debug.Log("Code Sent");
                        },
                        codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut: (id) =>
                        {
                            // Some codes
                        }
                    );
                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.Log(e.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("An error occurred while checking dependencies.");
            }
        });

    }


    public void VerifyCode()
    {
        string verificationId = PlayerPrefs.GetString("verificationId");
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = provider.GetCredential(verificationId, userVerificationCode.text);

        firebaseAuth.SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " +
                               task.Exception);
                return;
            }

            FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result.User;
            Debug.Log("User signed in successfully");
            // This should display the phone number.
            Debug.Log("Phone number: " + newUser.PhoneNumber);
            // The phone number providerID is 'phone'.
            Debug.Log("Phone provider ID: " + newUser.ProviderId);
            Debug.Log("Authentication Token : " + firebaseAuth.CurrentUser.TokenAsync(true));
        });
    }


}
```